# Why does this print nothing?

Tags: api, google-api, google-visualization

I am following there [instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/line_charts.html) to get a chart up and running and i cant seem to see why this chart is not displaying the data...maybe its late and i cant see the problem

```
 https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&#38;chxt=x,y&chxp=1,10,35,75&chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|March|April|May|1:|Min|Mid|Max
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it needs to be:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chxt=x,y&chxp=1,10,35,75&chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|March|April|May|1:|Min|Mid|Max
```

You have the `&#38;` instead of just `&`.

Comment: do you know how I add coordinates to the chart

Comment: Are you talking about points?
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_data_point_labels